# How to include input filename in error message?

Tags: macros, errors

I want to add an error message to a class I'm building for when the user (which will generally be me...) forgets or messes up a macro call sequence.  I can do this:

```
\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\MyClass@requiredvalue}
{\ClassError{myclass}{Entry requires version selection using
      \protect\selectversion \on@line}{}}
{}}
```

in the later part of the sequence, but because I've got a bunch of files that are included into each other, the line number is not helpful without the filename.  Is there some way to get the filename there in addition to/instead of the line number?

Comment: You could introduce a command that holds the filename at the beginning of each input file......

Answer (score 1):

The [`currfile` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/currfile) provides several methods to get the name and the path of the current file. For instance, you can use the `\currfilename` macro:

```
\ClassError{myclass}{Entry requires version selection using
  \protect\selectversion \on@line (\currfilename)}{}
```

Note that it might not work in some cases. For instance, if you load the `currfile` package in a class definition file, `\currfilename` will give the tex document filename instead of the class definition filename. Every file loaded after that will yield correct results.